# Determine whether field of interface-type of struct is set

Tags: go, reflection

Given a struct who's fields are of interface types:

```
type A interface { Foo() }
type B interface { Bar() }

type container struct {
   FieldA A
   FieldB B
   ...
}
```

And structs that implement those interfaces:

```
type a struct {}
func (*a) Foo() {}
func NewA() *a { return &a{} }

type b struct {}
func (*b) Bar() {}
func NewB() *b { return &b{} }
```

And code that creates an instance of `container` but does not explicitly set all fields:

```
c := &container{}
c.FieldA = NewA()
// c.FieldB = NewB()  // <-- FieldB not explicitly set
```

Using reflection, how can I detect the fields that were not explicitly set?

Inspecting the value of FieldB at runtime, VSCode happily reports the value to be `nil`. Likewise, attempting to invoke c.FieldB.Bar() will panic with nil pointer dereference. But reflection wont allow you test for IsNil, nor does IsZero return true:

```
func validateContainer(c *container) {
    tC := reflect.TypeOf(*c)
    for i := 0; i < tC.NumField(); i++ {
        reflect.ValueOf(tC.Field(i)).IsNil() // panics
        reflect.ValueOf(tC.Field(i)).IsZero() // always false
        reflect.ValueOf(tC.Field(i)).IsValid() // always true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the fields of `reflect.ValueOf(*c)` instead of `reflect.TypeOf(*c)`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func validateContainer(c *container) {
    tC := reflect.TypeOf(*c)
    vC := reflect.ValueOf(*c)
    for i := 0; i < vC.NumField(); i++ {
        if f := vC.Field(i); f.Kind() == reflect.Interface {
            fmt.Printf("%v: IsNil: %v, isZero: %v, IsValid: %v\n",
                tC.Field(i).Name,
                f.IsNil(),
                f.IsZero(),
                f.IsValid(),
            )
        }
    }

    // tC.Field(i) returns a reflect.StructField that describes the field.
    // It's not the field itself.
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", reflect.ValueOf(tC.Field(0)))
}

type A interface{ Foo() }
type B interface{ Bar() }

type container struct {
    FieldA A
    FieldB B
}

type a struct{}

func (*a) Foo() {}
func NewA() *a  { return &a{} }

func main() {
    c := &container{}
    c.FieldA = NewA()
    validateContainer(c)
}
```

Output:

```
FieldA: IsNil: false, isZero: false, IsValid: true
FieldB: IsNil: true, isZero: true, IsValid: true
reflect.StructField{Name:"FieldA", PkgPath:"", Type:(*reflect.rtype)(0x48de20), Tag:"", Offset:0x0, Index:[]int{0}, Anonymous:false}
```